# Rotate persp3d plot and save images as png

Tags: r, data-visualization

With R, I am using the `persp3d` function of the `rgl` package to get a nice 3d plot.

Now I want to rotate the `persp3d` function and save each small rotated image as a png file. I want then to include the png in my latex presentation with the command `animategraphic`.

I therefore want to aks, how I can do this?

I need them in a way that I can implement them in latex, so the names of the png files should somehow be like a1,a2 and so on...

My code to create the persp3d plot is:

```
persp3d(x, y, z, theta=50, phi=25, expand=0.75, col=color[zcol2],
        ticktype="detailed", xlab="", ylab="", zlab="",axes=FALSE)
```

I then tried to spin it with the `spin3d` command:

```
spind3d(rpm=3)
```

which does not work. Also this would not save pngs to my drive?

Comment: I also tried play3d( spin3d(rpm=1), duration=10) but it does not work neither save to my drive?

Comment: I also know about movie3d() but the command does also not work? Mh, I am confused why this is not working? And one more question: How can I implement this in LaTex having the same speed of rotation as in my R system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative using the functions `spin3d` to change the view, and `movie3d` to save the images.

```
library(rgl)
x <- seq(-10, 10, length= 30)
y <- x
f <- function(x,y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
z <- outer(x, y, f)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1
persp3d(x,y,z,theta=0,phi=25, col = "lightblue",
        ticktype="detailed", xlab="", ylab="", zlab="",axes=FALSE)
movie3d(spin3d(axis = c(0,0,1), rpm = 10), duration=6,  type = "png")
```

Note that by default `movie3d` saves the files in the folder set by `tempdir()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
x=1:10
y=1:10
z=matrix(runif(100),10,10)
persp3d(x,y,z,theta=50,phi=25)
```

then loop over theta or phi, use view3d to set the angle, snapshot3d to make a PNG

```
theta = seq(0,360,len=10)
for(i in 1:10){
 snapshot3d(file=paste0("spin-",i,".png"))
 view3d(theta=theta[i])
}
```

You might want to loop over phi instead of theta. Anyway, that gets you the PNGs you want, doesn't it?

Comment: +1 but isnt the a more "advanced" preimplemented function and not that brute force loop solution? But anyway thanks and I will accept it if there is no better answer!

Comment: If you say 'movie3d doesn't work' and 'spind3d doesn't work' without telling us exactly how, then I'm going to assume they don't work and make something that does!

Answer (score 3):

May be someone need. I used the following combination for persp3Drgl:

```
userMat = matrix(data = c( 0.4892255, 0.8709987, 0.04464279, 0,
                       -0.5228708, 0.2519508, 0.81430787, 0,
                       0.6980215, -0.4217298, 0.57868713, 0,
                       0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 1
                       ), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

persp3Drgl(..., userMatrix = userMat )
par3d( windowRect=c( 0,0,100,100 ) )
snapshot3d( file.path(plotDir, "3D.png"), top = TRUE )
```

Besides, I used to track `userMatrix` value (after rotation the plot by mouse) the following command

```
userMat = par3d(no.readonly=TRUE)$userMatrix
```

Comment: Very late to this, but this is extremely helpful, I'm surprised it does not have as many upvotes.